# Testing react-hook-form's V7 Controller API using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-hook-form

Is there a way to test a component that uses react-hook-form's [Controller API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) using Jest?

I'm trying to create a unit test component that is using the controller API to make a function radio button , as you can see in the code below;

```
<Controller
    name="test"
    control={control}
    defaultValue="one"
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        type="radio"
        name="test"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      >
        {collection.map((item) => (
          <ToggleButton key={item} value={item} variant="outline-primary">
            {item}
          </ToggleButton>
        ))}
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    )}
  />
```

I did try mocking Controller using the below for a snapshot test;

```
jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => {
  return {
    Controller: () => (<></>),
    useFormContext() {
      return {
        control: jest.fn(),
      }
    },
  }
})
```

I used the test below to debug just to check the component;

```
describe('PaymentOptions component', () => {
  it('renders correctly billet, pix and card credit radio button', () => {
    const { debug } = render(<PaymentOptions />)

    debug()
  })
})
```

But what is returned in the component has nothing to do with the component as shown in the image below;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvnWb.png)

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You mock worked for me! It solved an error I was getting that stated `methods.control` was undefined.